# "errmsg" : "server is not running with --replSet"

Tags: mongodb

i am creating replica set on my local system in  windows environment 
by following step

```
mkdir -p \srv\mongodb\rs0-0 \srv\mongodb\rs0-1 \srv\mongodb\rs0-2
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath \srv\mongodb\rs0-0 --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
mongod --port 27018 --dbpath \srv\mongodb\rs0-1 --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
mongod --port 27019 --dbpath \srv\mongodb\rs0-2 --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

and then

```
mongo shell type mongo --port 27017
rs.initiate()
```

but i am getttin error

```
"{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "server is not running with --replSet" }"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that before you launch your `mongod` processes you have no `mongod` process running ? I'm sure that a `mongod` process was already running. Retry and check that no process is already running.

Comment: FYI, you can double-check the command line options for a running `mongod` instance in the `mongo` shell with `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`. As per @kranteg's comment, I would suspect that you may have had a `mongod` instance running on port 27017 before you tried to start a replica set instance on the same port.

Comment: what version of mongodb?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Thanks to this question and previous answers I solved doing:

- I checked all the running mongod processes `ps -ef | grep mongo`. I had 1 mongo and 2 mongod processes
- I killed mongod with sudo `sudo killall mongod`
- and at the end I started with sudo `sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath \srv\mongodb\rs0-0 --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize` and it worked